# How can I make the pop up dialog invisible in android?

Tags: android

I would like to know how can I make the pop up dialog invisible in android? but still working, only diable.

```
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"#####onProviderDisabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("open gps");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("open GPS",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(
                        DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,
                        int paramInt) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    // get gps
                }
            });
    dialog.setNegativeButton(
            "not now",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(
                        DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,
                        int paramInt) {

                }
            });
    dialog.show();
}
```

};

Comment: What possible legitimate use is there for an invisible dialog?

Comment: Just a question, why ?

Comment: this popup dialog always popup , it is annoying, how to make it invisible

Comment: You can dismiss the popup.

Comment: anyknow??this popup dialog always popup when open an app, it is annoying, how to make it invisible but working

Comment: how to dismiss? can tell me more? thx so much

Comment: Uhhh...how are the users going to know where to tap if they can't see the button?

Comment: Or you can just don't call this method..

Comment: I have another way tell user to set gps. just don't want this dialog not open

Comment: Why do you still bother to show the dialog then, if you have another way?

Comment: this dialog was made by a friend, he is on vacation now. and i don't know why the nearby function must show the dialog to run, otherwise, nearby sometimes not work..anyone can help me ? thx

Answer (score 2):

To disable the dialog without removing the code completely, just comment out the line where you show the dialog:

```
// dialog.show();
```

This way the dialog won't appear, and if you want to show it again in a future version of your app you can just uncomment that line.

Comment: yes, I try this , but the find nearby function sometimes not working,

Comment: @LilyWong well that sounds like a different issue. What you wanted was to avoid showing the dialog, correct? Did this work?

Comment: yes...it was invisible but nearby function not working, can't show nearby users, if dialog show, all works.

Comment: @LilyWong well if you need the dialog, why are you trying to make it invisible? Is there something the dialog is doing in the background that you can do in the background of your activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"#####onProviderDisabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setMessage("open gps");
builder.setPositiveButton("open GPS",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(
                    DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,
                    int paramInt) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                        Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                // get gps
            }
        });
builder.setNegativeButton(
        "not now",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(
                    DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,
                    int paramInt) {

            }
        });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create():
alert.show();
}
```

And now when ever you want call alert.dismiss() to close the dialog.

Comment: hi,thanks first, but when i paste your code, it shows cannot resolve symbol  Builder in Builder.setMessage("open gps");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("open GPS",

Comment: Sorry about that. I made stupid error in typing the code

Comment: hi, noting changed, it still showing a popup dialog, I need no inivible the dialog.. anyway, thx so much

Comment: Did you call dialog.dismiss()? When u wanted to make it invisible?

Comment: how to call dialog.dismiss()? as i don't know too much android, can show me the codes ? thx so much!!!

Comment: you simply type dialog.dismiss() whenever you want to close the dialog. You can only close it, not make it invisible. Also, I would highly recommend learning and getting a strong understanding of Java before going into Android Apps since app revolves around Java and with a good foundation the whole process becomes extremely simple :) It's up to you though.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, show() is called, which will open the dialog. For closing the dialog you need to call dismiss() with same object. There is nothing like VISIBLE and INVISIBLE in AlertDialog.